# In the gtk source code, where do I find the code for creating the Page Setup dialog?

Tags: gtk, printers

I am interested in how gtk determines the printers to list in the page setup dialog and the print dialog.

In a number of functions in gtkpagesetup.h, there are calls to gtk_page_setup_new. The entire code in that function is:

```
GtkPageSetup *
gtk_page_setup_new (void)
{
  return g_object_new (GTK_TYPE_PAGE_SETUP, NULL);
}
```

So what is GTK_TYPE_PAGE_SETUP? It is defined in gtkpagesetup.h as:

```
#define GTK_TYPE_PAGE_SETUP    (gtk_page_setup_get_type ())
```

Also in gtkpagesetup.h is:

```
GType              gtk_page_setup_get_type          (void) G_GNUC_CONST;
```

But those are the only two places that gtk_page_setup_get_type is mentioned.

How do I locate the code that actually creates the Page Setup dialog?

Comment: Search on google about how to create widgets or costume widgets and you will notice the importance of those MACROS and how are those related to widgets. It is hard to give a simple explanation because you need to understand the whole picture here.

Comment: Having found `gtkpagesetup.h`, did you try looking in `gtkpagesetup.c`?